# Php form data not submitting on mysql databse with username check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

The form is loading on the registration page. But after giving any input it's not storing on MySQL database plus it also doesn't check for username availability.

**Here is HTML code part:**

```
<html>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    <div class ="cus_head">   </div>
<body>
<center> <h1 style="color:#1AAB30;">Register </h1>
 <form method="post" action="reg_process.php">
  UserName: <input type="text" name="cus_username" >
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $cus_username_err;?></span>
  <span id="username_status"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/users.js"></script>
  <br><br>
  First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstname_err;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastname_err;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Email Id: <input type="email" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $email_err;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $password_err;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
</center>
</body>
<div class ="cus_head">   </div>
```

Here is the Javascript file code for username availability: **users.js**

```
$('#username').keyup( function() {
    var username = $(this).val();

    $('#username_status').text('Searching...');

    if(username !== '') {
        $.post('php/username_check.php', { username: username}, function(data) {
            $('#username_status').text(data);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#username_status').text('');
    }
});
```

Here is the PHP Part: **register.php**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("%", "****", "****", "****");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
require 'username_check.php';
// define variables and set to empty values
$cus_username = $firstname = $lastname = $email = $password = "";
// defining variable and set to empty value for error
$cus_username_err = $firstname_err = $lastname_err = $email_err = $password_err = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST['cus_username'])) {
    $cus_username_err = "UserName is required";
  } else {
    $cus_username = sanitize($_POST['cus_username']);
  }

  if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $firstname_err = "First Name is required";
  } else {
   $firstname = sanitize($_POST['firstname']);
  }

  if (empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $lastname_err = "Last Name is required";
  } else {
    $lastname = sanitize($_POST['lastname']);
  }

   if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_err = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
  }

   if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $password_err = "password is required";
  } else {
  $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
  }

}
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO ***** (`cus_username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$cus_username', '$firstname', '$lastname','$email,'$password')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

function sanitize($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Here is the **username_check.php**

```html
            <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("%", "****", "*****", "*****");

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
    {
        $username = sanitize($_POST['username']);

        if (!empty($cus_username)) 
    { 
            $sql = "SELECT *FROM ***** WHERE username = '$username'";
                                           
             $count=mysqli_num_rows( $sql);
             if($count==0)
             {
               echo "Username doesn't exist";
               exit;
             }
            else
            {
              echo "Username already exists";
              exit;
            }
    }
}
function sanitize($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error in js or php ?

Comment: mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` is not recommended and more than likely explains why your `username check` is failing. The code is vulnerable to sql injection despite the `sanitize` function

Comment: Okay I edited the msqli part on username_check.php file. converted it into mysql. But still not working. I didn't add sanitize function on username_check. Will it require? Plus is sanitize function is not good enough for sql injection? then what you recommend?

Comment: no error in js or php, only warning, do not use super global variable directly.

Comment: use `mysqli` or `PDO` with `prepared statements` if you wish to avoid nasty surprises with SQL Injection. The `mysql` extensions are deprecated and removed from PHP 7+

Comment: Page name should be `reg_process.php` not `register.php` (see action in your form tag) and use `$username` instead of `$cur_username` in *username_check.php*.

Comment: converted the code into mysqli

Comment: @RohanKumar on form tag it is already reg_process.php not register.php please check correctly. Edited the $username. There was  typo but in actual database that field is named as cus_username. So isn't going to create any difference? thanks

Comment: I did all the suggested edit, its still doesn't work, mysql database is not updating.

Comment: @mimi you have your PHP part in `register.php`, please check your question again. *Here is the PHP Part: **register.php***

Comment: @RohanKumar Sorry Misunderstood, but I added form action to reg_process.php in order to redirect it to the next page for email verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to your `username check` script - as the ajax function is being triggered on `keyup` it is not likely that the entire field has been completed so using a `like` operator in the sql makes more sense. 
Rather than directly embedding a variable in the sql statement it is a far better option to use `prepared statements` - the statement here uses a questionmark as a placeholder which is later bound to a constructed string variable containing the contents of `$_POST['username']` at the time of the `keyup`

```
<?php
    /*
        username_check.php
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['username'] ) ){

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        $rows=0;
        /*
            sql prepared statement using `LIKE` operator
        */
        $sql='select * from `TABLE` where `username` like ?';
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );


        if( $stmt ){
            /* Bind the placeholder to an as yet undefined variable - $username */
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );

            /* Generate the $username variable with trailing % */
            $username = $_POST['username']."%";

            /* Query the db */
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if( $result ){
                /* If the query succeeded, get the row count */
                $stmt->store_result();
                $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
            }
            /* tidy up */
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        $db->close();

        /* Send response back to javascript callback */
        exit( $rows > 0 ? "Username already exists" : "Username doesn't exist" );
    }
?>
```

For the `register.php` script - again using `prepared statements` to avoid sql injection. Neither script is tested - they are for your guidance on how you might accomplish your goals

```
<?php
    /*
        register.php
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['cus_username'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] ) ){

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


        $sql = 'insert into `TABLE` (`cus_username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) values (?,?,?,?,?);';
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $username=!empty($_POST['cus_username']) ? $_POST['cus_username'] : false;
            $firstname=!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : false;
            $lastname=!empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : false;
            $email=!empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

            $errors=array();
            if( !$username )$errors[]='Please enter a username';
            if( !$password )$errors[]='Please enter your password';
            if( !$email )$errors[]='Please enter your email';
            if( !$firstname )$errors[]='Your firstname is required';
            if( !$lastname )$errors[]='Your lastname is required';

            if( empty( $errors ) ){

                /* bind the variables and execute the sql statement */
                $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password);
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                echo $result ? 'Success' : 'Failed';

            } else {
                foreach( $errors as $error ){
                    echo $error . '<br />';
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

### -- Updates

The html/php page to add a new user

```
<?php


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Add a user</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <style>
            html, html *{font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;font-size:0.85rem;}

            label{clear:both;margin:0.25rem;padding:0.25rem;display:block;width:30%;float:left;}
            input[type='submit']{margin:3rem 0;background:green;color:white;clear:both;float:left;}
            input[type='text'],
            input[type='email'],
            input[type='password']{float:right;}
            #username_status{color:red;margin:0 0 0 2rem;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method='post' action='reg_process.php'>
            <!-- the text field needs an id for the ajax function to glom onto -->
            <label for='cus_username'>UserName: <input type='text' name='cus_username' id='username' /><span id='username_status'></span></label>
            <label for='firstname'>First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname' /></label>
            <label for='lastname'>Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname' /></label>
            <label for='email'>Email Id: <input type='email' name='email' /></label>
            <label for='password'>Password: <input type='password' name='password' /></label>
            <!--

                various spans removed for testing
                and slight rearrangement using `label`

            -->
            <input type='submit' />  
        </form>
        <!-- 
            rather than sending an ajax request with each character typed
            I updated this to check for a minimal length before sending the
            request and also changed the event listener to listen for blur events
            so there should only be one request when the user moves to the next
            field in the form
        -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#username').blur( function(e) {
                var status=$('#username_status');
                    status.text( 'Searching...' );

                if( $( this ).val() !== '' && $( this ).val().length > 3 ) {
                    $.post('php/username_check.php', { username: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
                        status.text( data );
                    });
                } else {
                    status.text('');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    /*
        username_check.php
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['username'] ) ){

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        $rows=0;
        /*
            sql prepared statement using `LIKE` operator
        */
        $sql='select * from `users` where `username` like ?';
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );


        if( $stmt ){
            /* Bind the placeholder to an as yet undefined variable - $username */
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );

            /* Generate the $username variable with trailing % */
            $username = $_POST['username']."%";

            /* Query the db */
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if( $result ){
                /* If the query succeeded, get the row count */
                $stmt->store_result();
                $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
            }
            /* tidy up */
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        $db->close();

        /* Send response back to javascript callback */
        exit( $rows > 0 ? "Username already exists" : "Username doesn't exist" );
    }
?>

<?php
    /*
        reg_process.php
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['cus_username'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] ) ){

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


        $sql = 'insert into `users` (`cus_username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) values (?,?,?,?,?);';

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $username=!empty($_POST['cus_username']) ? $_POST['cus_username'] : false;
            $firstname=!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : false;
            $lastname=!empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : false;
            $email=!empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

            $errors=array();
            if( !$username )$errors[]='Please enter a username';
            if( !$password )$errors[]='Please enter your password';
            if( !$email )$errors[]='Please enter your email';
            if( !$firstname )$errors[]='Your firstname is required';
            if( !$lastname )$errors[]='Your lastname is required';

            if( empty( $errors ) ){

                /* bind the variables and execute the sql statement */
                $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password );
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                echo $result ? 'Success' : 'Failed';

            } else {
                foreach( $errors as $error ){
                    echo $error . '<br />';
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

I created these three pages following the directory structure suggested by the javascript function and form target, changed the db details to suit dev environment and assumed a table called `users` - ran the page and completed the form. A new user was successfully added.

Comment: Hi tried it using your code, but it didn't work. data is still not adding on mysql database. I am using XAMPP on Server Type MariaDB. Is that is a reason it didn't worked? Sorry I am new in PHP coding.

Comment: are there any errors in the php error log relating to this?

Comment: no error just warning, do not use super global variable directly using netbeans

Comment: I had a doubt about database connection, so I created a separate conn.php file with connection code only. That is giving me following error: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mimiphp\conn.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mimiphp\conn.php on line 7
Connected successfully

Comment: Presumably you did actually edit the code and insert the correct database connection details and table names? Does the `check_username` script work? Trying using debugging breakpoints in the code at various points to see where the logic gets - if it fails at any point etc

Comment: username_check script doesn't show anything when I input the username on register.php page. Yes, I changed the database connection details & table names also at the sql query changed username to cus_username because on database table header is known as cus_username on username_check.php code

Comment: as I am adding the 1st data so I guess username will be available. But I am not sure why data is not inserted into the database. I also changed the java script code to <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="users.js"></script> & added two .js files on same directory where .php files are located.

Comment: Also I double check the connection, created new user with localhost. Added & updated on all script for connection. It connects successfully. But still database is not updating. Also forgot to mention, I added this extra line on registar.php require 'username_check.php'; in order to connect it.

Comment: I have just now looked ( for the 1st time properly ) at the HTML - is that the actual HTML or just bits? If it is then it is NOT valid HTML... You cannot have HTML elements in the head or after the body

Comment: Thank you for your code, you have taught me how to fish. I did the necessary changes, for username_check.php I edited it as $sql='select * from customer where cus_username like ?'; as table is customer & field name is cus_username. Now what I am seeing, after giving my 1st input at username, it stuck at "searching..." .It keep showing "searching.." even after typing all the fields. Also database is still not updating.

Comment: With Bind parameters is it possible to do salting with hash for password?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not - generate the hash, assign to a variable and then bind the variable. You can't ( afaik ) bind directly to a function return value, hence assign as a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your effort & Sharing the code, the hashing idea, it worked. I made some typo mistake that's why data wasn't submitting. Now its working perfectly.

Comment: Just one problem is the "searching..." keep showing up on all input, even after not finding any duplicate username. Also for duplicate value, it keeps showing "Searching..."Does the Javascript '#username' & '#username_status' and username form id & span id all which is 'username' all need to change into cus_username?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146176/discussion-between-ramraider-and-mimi).